# How to get data from elasticsearch like jon query

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have users, teams and athletes document. User document has an array of object related with team ids. After match a key with user filed I need to get the related data from teams within a single query.

I have something like below

```
"size": 20,
"query": {
  "bool": {
  "filter" : [
    {"terms" : { "_type" :["users","athletes"] }}
   ],
   "should":[{
     "multi_match" : {
          "query":searchQuery, 
          "type":"cross_fields",
          "fields":["firstName", "email","lastName","name"],
          "minimum_should_match": "80%" 
        }
    }
   ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: **I don't recommend using "join queries between to seperate types with ELS**. In [ELS documentation about "Joining queries"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) : *Performing full SQL-style joins in a distributed system like Elasticsearch is prohibitively expensive. Instead, Elasticsearch offers two forms of join which are designed to scale horizontally.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch is limited in this respect, but you could query for athletes and get the respective team using an [has_child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) query.

In order to use the `has_child` query you will need to establish in the index definition a parent child relationship between the team and the athlete:

PUT sports

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "team" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "athlete" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "_parent" : {
          "type" : "team"
        },
        "_routing" : {
          "required" : true
        },
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `"_parent"` element.

Then you will need to add some data to the parent entity (team):

PUT sports/team

```
{
  "name" : "A"
}
```

Then you will need to index some athletes associating these to the parent:

PUT sports/athlete?parent=dc2b3e8f-7dea-4898-9852-538c0d0367f4

```
{
  "name" : "Gil Fernandes"
}
```

Note that "dc2b3e8f-7dea-4898-9852-538c0d0367f4" is the id of a team in Elastic Search

Finally you can execute the has_child query:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 20,
  "_source" : true,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "has_child" : {
          "type" : "athlete",
          "query" : {
            "match" : {
              "name" : "Gil Fernandes"
            }
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

You will get as a result the team of the athlete:

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "sports",
      "_type" : "team",
      "_id" : "dc2b3e8f-7dea-4898-9852-538c0d0367f4",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "name" : "A"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find this answer useful or not? Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I solved that problem in my way. Yes, your answer is useful.